# Match a lookup table df custom function, cannot mutate with it get 'problem with input'

Tags: r

Rather than use joins, I need a custom function to prevent returning multiple matches. In this case I just try to get the first match/row using head(1).

Some data:

```
example_df <- data.frame(
  url = c('blog/blah', 'blog/?utm_medium=foo', 'blah', 'subscription/apples', 'UK/something'),
  numbs = 1:5
)

lookup_df <- data.frame(
  string = c('subscription', 'UK', 'blog'),
  group = c('subs', 'UK', 'blog2')
)


lookup_func <- function(str, lut) {
# lookup str in lut$string, return just one row/match  
  
  # works with e.g.
  # str = 'blog'
  # lut = lookup_df

  lut %>% filter(str_detect(.[['string']], str)) %>% head(1) %>% pull(group)
}

example_df %>% 
  mutate(blah = lookup_func(url, lookup_df))
```

Gives:

```
 Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `blah`.
x Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 3 or 1, not size 5.
ℹ Input `..1` is `str_detect(.[["string"]], str)`.
ℹ Input `blah` is `lookup_func(url, lookup_df)`.
```

If I run just `lut %>% filter(str_detect(.[['string']], str)) %>% head(1) %>% pull(group)` after setting variables str and lut per the commented out lines it does return the desired string, 'blah2', just not when I attempt as a function.

How can I mutate() with my custom function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using data.table:

```
example_df %>% as.data.table %>% .[, blah := lookup_func(url, lookup_df), by=url] %>% print
```

also I think you want to lookup 2nd table in the 1st one not vice versa, so your lookup_func should be changed:

```
lookup_func <- function(str, lut) {
  # lookup str in lut$string, return just one row/match  
  
  # works with e.g.
  # str = 'blog'
  # lut = lookup_df
  
  lut %>% filter(str_detect(str, .[['string']])) %>% head(1) %>% pull(group)
}
```